# Sufficient or necessary conditions for irrational numbers.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Today in class we saw that the sum of an irrational with a rational gives an irrational, but not necessarily that the sum of irrationals gives an irrational.

And I was wondering what sufficient or necessary conditions you would have to satisfy two irrational numbers $a$ and $b$ for their sum to be irrational. Could someone help me with an answer.

Comment: This is not a simple thing. In general it is still an open problem. For example, it is not known whether $\pi +e$ is irrational. [A search for "sum of irrational numbers"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+of+irrational+numbers) will get you many details.

Comment: $\pi$ is irrational. $-\pi$ is irrational aswell. Their sum is $0$, which is rational. Even for multiplication (take $\sqrt2$ for example).

Comment: Irrationality proofs are usually extremely hard , there are however some sufficient conditions that guarantee that a number is even transcendental , for example the condition used in the Gelfond Schneider theorem.